# Android - Get only accessible collections in Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I currently have security rules that allow a user to read only from a collection named "153".

In Android, I access Firestore and call `.collection("153").get()...` on the Firestore instance to retrieve data from that collection.

If, instead, the Android code reads `.collection("999").get...`, the permission is denied, as it should be.

Security Rules:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // FULL ADMIN ACCESS
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == 'XYZ1234XYEDFC';
    }
    // 153 READ
    match /153/{x} {
        allow read: if request.auth.uid == 'XYZ12234XTZ';
    }
    // 999 READ
    match /999/{x} {
        allow read: if request.auth.uid == 'ABC1234ABC';
    }
  }
}
```

What is the method to allow an app user, who is signed in via Firestore, to only read a collection they have access to in Security Rules **without** hardcoding the collection?

Edit:

I have an existing database in Firestore. The database has many top-level collections with documents in each. Each app user will have access to one or many of the collections.

Right now, I can only see how to call upon a specific collection by giving the collection path. Can I get all collections that a UID has access to, programmatically?

Comment: Could you edit the question to illustrate better when your last sentence means?  Are you working with an existing database structure?  Please also show your existing security rules.

Comment: I have edited and added my security rules

Answer (score 1):

You can use a document within Firestore to configure Firestore rules.  Here's an example - you'll likely have to modify it to meet your specific needs, based on your actual collections.

Firstly, you're going to need a way to identify which collections should have this per-user authentication.  Let's assume, for simplicity, that the collection name starts with an "X".  Your pattern may differ.  But you do absolutely need a way to distinguish them from other collections that shouldn't have special protection, otherwise you won't be able to store other types of data.

Second, define a new collection called "config", and create a document in there called "permissions".  This document can contain fields for each of the collections to protect.  The value of these fields will be the UID that can access all documents in the collection.  Here: UID1 can access Xcollection1, and UID2 can access Xcollection2:

```
/config/permissions
  Xcollection1: UID1
  Xcollection2: UID2
```

Now, add this rule:

```
match /{coll}/{document=**} {
  allow read, write: if coll[0] == "X" && get(/config/permissions).data[coll] == request.auth.uid
}
```

What this rule does is firstly check to see if the collection being accessed (wildcard `coll`) should have per-user protection (it begins with "X"), and secondly check the contents of the /config/permissions document to see if the user's UID (`request.auth.uid`) has been assigned access to the collection.

You may want something different or more sophisticated, but the idea is that you can use a document in Firestore to configure Firestore rules using the [get()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore#.get) function.

Comment: I understand your solution is a powerful way of authenticating access, and I will use it, though I'm still uncertain on how to utilize this method to query all accessible collections in Android. Are you suggesting that config/permissions is readable by all UIDs, then we call get() on config/permissions document and store all keys that match our UID value, then perform get() on those collection keys? Not sure if that would be a security flaw...

Comment: No, but it sounds like you have a requirement that was not stated in the question.  Your question makes it sound like clients already know which collections the want to access.  You didn't say anything about clients knowing the list of collections they may access.  But that's just a matter of a making a single document readable by a uid, giving it an id of the uid.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. Please let me try to explain. A client may access many top-level collections, and all documents inside those collections. The documents will only be read from, never written to, by the client - they are written externally. I was hoping there is a method in which you can loop over all top-level collections, checking each collection name against security rules for permission, or some alternative approach. I can't make single docs readable by a UID because the collection(s) in which to look in are not known client-side. Should I post this as a separate Q?

Comment: There is no API to iterate top level collections.  A search should discover that.  You will need some other way to get that list.  There is no way to programmatically discover if a user has access to something, other than for the user to actually try to access it.  It sounds like what you're trying to do is not really feasible.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem and now I found a alternate way to solve this. First of all make a spinner which contains the name of collections[make sure collection names and spinner item names should be same] and user will be able to select a collection they belong to[considering user know which collection they have to choose].Considering the above security rule, programmatically you can implement it by passing the spinner value: `i.putExtra("any keyword",variable_ name);`

In onCreate:

```
 ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter1=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(LoginActivity.this,R.array.Company, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter1);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

In login method:

```
firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(LoginActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {

                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {


                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                pd.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Welcome", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                String text1 = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                                Intent i= new Intent( getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                                i.putExtra("spin",text1);
                                startActivity(i);
                            }
```

In MainActivity :

```
Intent intent =getIntent();
    String a = intent.getStringExtra("spin"); //'a' stores the value of collection
    switch(a){
        case "153":
            showData1(a); //This method will retrieve data in that particular collection with a parameter used 
            break;
        case "999":
            showData1(a);
            break;
    }
```

In showData:

```
private void showData1(String col) {
    pd.getProgress();
    db.collection(String.valueOf(col))
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {.......
```

That's the method I found out to allow a particular user to access a particular collection.